# HP EliteDesk 800 G5 SFF cannot get display with discrete graphics card Nvidia G210

Tags: graphics-card, bios, nvidia-graphics-card, hp

I bought a used HP EliteDesk 800 G5 Small Form Factor (PN: 6BD64AV) PC and installed an Nvidia G210 1GB 64bit discrete graphics card to x16 slot. It worked at first and I was able to get display to 2 monitors.

Then, I entered the BIOS and it was password protected. I reset the BIOS using the jumper and but the graphics card not working anymore. I tried changing some settings at BIOS (disable Secure Boot etc.) and updated the BIOS but no avail.

The G210 is not listed in Windows Device Manager (I tried show hidden devices option). I tried to install the Nvidia driver but the installer says *"This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware."* (The OS is Windows 10 Pro 22H2 64bit)

I am able to get display from the onboard graphics but I need to use the discrete graphics card and I have no idea why it is not working anymore.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Did the discrete graphics card draw too much power from the small machine?  Can you run hardware diagnostics on the card to see if it has failed?

Comment: I don't know to run diagnostics on the graphics card, because the system doesn't detect it. I run the board diagnostics and here is the result. https://i.imgur.com/f7DC04E.png I don't think the power will be problem because G210 draws max. 31W and the PSU is 250W and the system config. is i5-9500 8GB DDR4 240GB SSD G210 + Wired Keyboard&Mouse.

Comment: Based on your response, it would appear the discrete card has a hardware issue. Perhaps take the machine to a local PC shop for proper diagnosis.

Comment: @John thank you for your response. It turns out the graphics card is faulty. I just tried another card of the same model and it works. The initial card had worked at the beginning. And this misguided me to think that the cause is some bizarre BIOS setting. Thank you.